# Не могу понять смысл

Tags: смысл

Мне на моё заявление об участии в программе пришёл такой ответ:

> "Ваше заявление согласовано"

Скажите, пожалуйста, что это значит?

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, возможность вашего участия в программе *подтверждена* теми, от кого это зависит. Получившие ваше заявление **согласовали** ваше (выраженное в заявлении) пожелание с отвечающими за решение коллегами.